# Execute an expression rather than calling a method inside custom Vue directives

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using the following Vue directive to detect clicks outside an element:

```
Vue.directive('click-outside', {
    bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
      el.clickOutsideEvent = function (event) {
        // here I check that click was outside the el and his childrens
        if (!(el == event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
          // and if it did, call method provided in attribute value
          vnode.context[binding.expression](event);
        }
      };
      document.body.addEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
    },
    unbind: function (el) {
      document.body.removeEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
    },
  });
```

Works well when I provide a method, like this:

```
<div id="profile-list-container" v-click-outside="closeProfiles">
```

but when I put a direct expression inside the attribute it doesn't do anything:

```
<div id="profile-list-container" v-click-outside="isProfileOpen = false">
```

I see that the line  vnode.contextbinding.expression; is what is wrong, but I'm not sure how to change it to make it work.

Comment: because `binding.expression` is one string, then causes `vnode.context[binding.expression]` is undefined. And `v-click-outside="isProfileOpen = false"` will be executed directly when complie template. Probably you'd like to use `()=>{isProfileOpen = false}` instead.

Comment: @Sphinx that will just try to resolve `vnode.context[() => {isProfileOpen = false}](event)` which definitely isn't right.

Comment: @Bert, sure, so we have to check the `typeof binding.value` then apply different approaches... probably there are some better solution, hopefully someone can point out...

Comment: @Sphinx Yes, your answer is better. Seems like a lot of work to avoid passing a method (as restricted by OP, not you).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because binding.expression is one string, then causes `vnode.context[binding.expression]` is undefined, so `vnode.context[binding.expression](value)` will fail.

Then check [Vue Github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5588), it describes why `v-click-outside="isProfileOpen = false"` will not work, you can 
check the demo (test case 3) see what will happen.

If you can convert to `v-click-outside="()=>{showDiv1 = !showDiv1}"`, below is **one sample**:

```js
let vMyDirective = {}
vMyDirective.install = function install (_Vue) {

  _Vue.directive('click-outside', {
    bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
      el.clickOutsideEvent = function (event) {
        // here I check that click was outside the el and his childrens
        if (!(el == event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
          // and if it did, call method provided in attribute value
          //console.log(binding.value, binding.expression)
          if(typeof binding.value==='function') {
            binding.value.bind(vnode.context)(event)
          } else {
            let expression = ''
            let beg = ["'", '`', '"'].includes(binding.expression[0]) ? 1 : 0
            let count = ["'", '`', '"'].includes(binding.expression[binding.expression.length -1]) ? binding.expression.length -1 : binding.expression.length
            expression = binding.expression.substring(beg, count)
            new Function(expression).bind(vnode.context)(event)
          }
        }
      };
      document.body.addEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
    },
    unbind: function (el) {
      document.body.removeEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
    },
  })
}

Vue.use(vMyDirective)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      showDiv1: true,
      showDiv2: true,
      showDiv3: true
    }
  },
  methods:{
    clickOutside: function (ev) {
      console.log('test case 1', ev.toString())
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>Test</div>
  <div v-click-outside="clickOutside">
    Test Case 1
  </div>
  <div v-click-outside="()=>{showDiv1 = !showDiv1}">
    Test Case 2: 
    <span v-show="showDiv1" style="background-color:red">Test Case 2: You clicked outside!!!</span>
  </div>
  <div v-click-outside="showDiv2 = false">
    Test Case 3: 
    <span v-show="showDiv2" style="background-color:red">Test Case 3: You will see showDiv2 is false...!!!</span>
  </div>
  <div v-click-outside="`this.showDiv3 = !this.showDiv3`">
    Test Case 4: 
    <span v-show="showDiv3" style="background-color:red">Test Case 4: You clicked outside!!!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems very weird to me that I can use a string within Vue's default actions like v-click and I have to pass an anonymous function on a custom directive. To keep code uniformity, I would really rather pass the string directly and treat it within the directive. Any ideas on how to do that? I can see that I could check for type and use eval() on the passed string, but still, it wouldn't be inside Vue's context so it would'nt behave like a normal v-click attribute. Any thoughts?

Comment: @raphadko you can look into the link in the answer, the Vue team said v-on is one exception... so i don’t think you can work around it ...

Comment: @raphadko I added some codes (check test case 4) to support passing one string (not expression), but I don't think it is better than `()=>{...}`.

Comment: Thanks @Sphinx. Code uniformity on the view part is very important in my project, that's why, if I'm extending Vue behavior, I would rather extend just like other Vue behaviours, I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Quick question though, why isn't eval() an option?

Comment: @raphadko, check [Javascript MDN: eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!)